# Swift 2.1 New Way to Initialize String Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

In my old Swift 1 code I could do this:

```
class MyArrayLists {

    var myarray = [String, String]

    init(){

        myarray.append("First String", "Second String.")
    }

}
```

Now after getting around to opening my code and trying to convert it to 2.1, it's telling me I can't do this anymore. Next to the declaration we see:

> Expected member name or constructor call

Next to the append statement I see:

> Cannot invoke append with argument of type (String, String)

What changed?

Comment: what is my array supposed to be? An array of strings, an array of a 2-string-tuples?

Comment: Hey, it seems like you want to use a Dictionary, in that case replace var myarray = [String, String] to var myarray = [String: String]()

To add you could use myarray["DictID"] = "DictValue"

Comment: No I need two strings in an array, it's not a key and value sort of thing it's two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Swift 2 you explicitly have to declare the type of object in the array in parenthesis:

```
class MyArrayLists {

    var myarray: [(String, String)] = [(String, String)]()

    init(){

        self.myarray.append(("First String", "Second String."))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler used to *infer* that

```
[String, String]
```

was actually an array of tuples:

```
[(String, String)]
```

and that appending a pair of values with

```
myarray.append("First String", "Second String.")
```

was sytactic sugar for what actually was happening behind the scene:

```
myarray.append(("First String", "Second String."))
```

But now this automatic conversion has been deprecated.

The solution is to declare the proper type, and to append a proper tuple:

```
var myarray = [(String, String)]()

myarray.append(("First String", "Second String."))
```